# Check Condition for M to N numbers without using looping statements

Tags: java, random

So the question is:

The user has to specify 2 no's **M** (starting point) and **N** (ending point)

the program has to check all the numbers between M and N with these conditions:

- if divisible by 3 print "divisible by 3"
- if divisible by 5 print "divisible by 5"
- if divisible by 3 and 5 print "divisible by both"

Solution in java would be very much appreciated
only if looping is allowed to check the condition

Comment: Payment in `dollars` would be appreciated!

Comment: Why did you apply `random` tag?

Comment: @Jai: i came up with nothing so far :/

Comment: @ShadowKnight - Then you came to this site too early. You will need to go through Java tutorials first and only when you have **specific** problems or questions, come back here, show your code and we'll discuss.

Comment: A simple search on google should get you going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my stab at it, and the process of is called `Recursion`.

```
public class Main {

    private static int M, N;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        M = 0; // min value
        N = 10; // max value
        noLoop(M); // begin the method
    }

    private static void noLoop(int currentNumber) {
        String resultMessage;

        if (currentNumber % 3 == 0) {
            resultMessage = currentNumber + " is divisible by 3.";
        } else {
            resultMessage = currentNumber + " is NOT divisible by 3.";
        }

        if (currentNumber % 5 == 0) {
            resultMessage = currentNumber + " is divisible by 5.";
        } else {
            resultMessage = currentNumber + " is NOT divisible by 5.";
        }

        if (currentNumber % 3 == 0 && currentNumber % 5 == 0) {
            resultMessage = currentNumber + " is divisible by BOTH 3 and 5.";
        }

        System.out.println(resultMessage);
        M++; // min value + 1
        if (M <= N) { // if min value == max value, STOP!
            noLoop(M);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want it recursively

```
 void func(int M,int N)
{ 
if (M>N)
return;
 else
  {
   i=M;
    if(i%5==0 && i%3==0){

       system.out.println(i + "is divisible by both 3 and 5");

    }else if(i%5==0){

       system.out.println(i + "is divisible by  5");

    }else if(i%3==0){

       system.out.println(i + "is divisible by  3");

    }
    func(M++,N);
 }

}
```

Comment: I think the title suggests he needs recursion.

Comment: yep I am working on it

Comment: you call the function as func(m,n);